# "heroku db:push" gives me: "Taps Load Error: no such file to load -- sqlite3..."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

By doing this:

```
bundle exec heroku db:push
```

I got this:

```
 !    Taps Load Error: no such file to load -- sqlite3
 !    You may need to install or update the taps gem to use db commands.
 !    On most systems this will be:
 !    
 !    sudo gem install taps
```

This is my database.yml file:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: g_dev
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
```

Comment: I debuged it in the meantime

I need to put gem 'sqlite3' in the gemfile.

Because of line 10 of cli.rb (taps-0.3.24):

      require 'sqlite3'

It's in taps source code... :( I have no choice

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I debuged it.

I need to put gem 'sqlite3' in the gemfile.

Because of this line 10 in cli.rb (taps-0.3.24):

```
require 'optparse'
require 'tempfile'
require 'taps/monkey'
require 'taps/config'
require 'taps/log'
require 'vendor/okjson'

Taps::Config.taps_database_url = ENV['TAPS_DATABASE_URL'] || begin
  # this is dirty but it solves a weird problem where the tempfile disappears mid-process
  require 'sqlite3'
```

It's in taps source code... :( I have no choice

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, but it suffices to just do:

```
gem install sqlite3
```

to make it available locally. That is, you do not need to pollute your gemfile with sqlite.

(Use sudo according to your environment.)